# How to run multiple tasks in parallel in yaml pipeline in Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In  yaml pipeline I have multiple tas=sk: Docker@2 and ECRImagepush@1 in parallel.  I am looking for an option to run all these Docker@2 together with its ECRPushImage@1 in parallel to reduce the overall build time.

Comment: The unit of parallelism in Azure Pipelines is jobs. Break your pipeline up into multiple jobs.